# How to check value of key in Object and use it in if statement? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

**I'am a real beginner and just enthusiast of JavaScript.** I need help. I've got problem with code below:

```
if (newTask.done === false) {
        newTask = doneArray.push({
            id: doneArray.length,
            description: clickedTask.textContent,
            done: false
        });
    } else {
    removeTask = doneArray.splice(newTask.id, 1);
    };
```

I need to check if my object have *false* or *true* **value** in done **key**. When new task have false I want to **push** it to my **Array**, and if not **remove** it from my Array. I don't know how to take value of id and use it in **if statement**. Then change that value in object into *true*. I don't know, maybe there is much better way to make it work and not deleting whole code. Here is full code:
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Lynthius/pen/xxbYxvB?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=16ec2ffdba5801f57364dd2ab55a963eb2b25356-1578597069-0-AVQfYfDRfSVAVYxvmmlLkAdtnKA3j5e4MrRmMZ2hPb0C1m8R3QpXdiBI92JhrMEhi4BJc32a0tgSogjeHiFr-eKCJUg0jMIcvlcY9b980YBxtdTsgMFT5ufpnhajmBJmD1p20tm2N76u-x7dumid0qM0nOVlZcm1s_QSiIqEpPZEeHiYfAsD0h8veskOxWOvK3jdqkt0lrodyZED074XG9fYdUD51SA_U4A9Mu4v62hyPhH0bRB0mhl5tcW4x-llZ1k0P8-0M9_X44OxzG4iTz2ehsn1-Rl3UG3uQz5wlTpLa1i62NMaesqdd8qKB7nSziGWgorXaLnTKaRnxllqDkgVo8t2UrBBMDzCrujOIMZWcawaMWhy7VgFKobORLCRVmhdOX3fXMhnUWnpQSnkxRs)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple approach that should help you achieve your goal. Check the comments for details and leave a comment if unclear:

```js
// Here is an array containing 3 new tasks
const allTasks = [{
  id: 0,
  description: 'desc 1',
  done: true
}, {
  id: 1,
  description: 'desc 2',
  done: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  description: 'desc 3',
  done: true
}];

// Here is an function to get a new array of only NOT DONE tasks
// We achieve this by simply using Array.prototype.filter method
const filterDoneTasks = arr => arr.filter(task => !task.done);

const pendingTasks = filterDoneTasks(allTasks);

console.log(pendingTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. ..

```
if (newTask.done === false) {
    newTask = doneArray.push({
        id: doneArray.length,
        description: clickedTask.textContent,
        done: false
    });
} else {
    for(let i = 0; i < doneArray.length; ++i){
       if(doneArray[i].id == newTask.id)
           removeTask = doneArray.splice(i, 1);
           break;
       }
} };
```

However, every time you remove an object from the array the length should get smaller, causing multiple objects with the same ID. this means you will have to decide to do a remove first operation, or remove all operation for the array. I would use a different ID like a counter that always goes up, unless this is intentional.

edit-- it may also just be length starts at 1 and array index starts at 0. so you have to account for that if the wrong number is being removed.